# How do I do multiple syncs using a DBChangeTracker?

Tags: javascript, html, synchronization

I'm using SequelSphere to store data for a webapp, and I'm using change trackers to track the changes.  The first time I sync, the tracker returns the changed rows.  The second time I sync, the tracker returns both the first and second set of changed rows.  Here is what I'm doing:

```
// create my tracker
var tracker = db.changeTrackers.create("order_tracker", ["orders"]);

// insert first set of orders
for (var i = 0; i < firstOrders; ++i)
    db.insertRow("orders", firstOrders[i]);

// sync orders up
performSync(db.changeTrackers.get("order_tracker").getChangedRows());

// insert more orders (second set)
for (var i = 0; i < secondOrders; ++i)
    db.insertRow("orders", secondOrders[i]);

// sync second set of orders up
performSync(db.changeTrackers.get("order_tracker").getChangedRows());
```

The first sync works fine.  The second sync is sending up all the orders from the first set and the second.  I only want it to return the second set.  How can I get it to return just the second set?

Comment: Also, there was no SequelSphere tag.  How can I get a SequelSphere tag added to this post?

Comment: If there is no such tag, then that means it is not that popular and you can not add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for the API for a DBChangeTracker: [SequelSphere API](http://www.sequelsphere.com/dbdocs/api-documentation/)

There are actually two ways to answer your question:

1)  Use the "clearChanges()" method to remove all of the changes from your DBChangeTracker.  You can do it "logically" right after the sync:

```
// sync orders up
var tracker = db.changeTrackers.get("order_tracker");
performSync(tracker.getChangedRows());
tracker.clearChanges();
```

2)  If the data synchronization occurrs asynchronously, end the tracking and use a second change tracker to hold the new changes:

```
// End first set of changes in tracker, start second
var trackerOne = db.changeTrackers.get("order_tracker");
trackerOne.endTracking();
var trackerTwo = db.changeTrackers.create("order_tracker_2", ["orders"]);
// sync orders up
performSync(tracker.getChangedRows());
// Get rid of first tracker
db.changeTrackers.drop("order_tracker");
```

Let me know if this is sufficient!

Comment: Yup.  I figured out how to use multiple change trackers, and went that way.